# devise_token_auth & Rails 5 - IndexError: string not matched

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, http-token-authentication

I'm trying to sign in an existing user using `devise_token_auth` version `0.1.38`, but I'm hitting an `IndexError: string not matched` in the library's `sessions_controller`.

```
IndexError (string not matched):

devise_token_auth (0.1.38) app/controllers/devise_token_auth/sessions_controller.rb:37:in `[]='
devise_token_auth (0.1.38) app/controllers/devise_token_auth/sessions_controller.rb:37:in `create'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
```

The relevant code from `sessions_controller` is:

```
  if @resource and valid_params?(field, q_value) and @resource.valid_password?(resource_params[:password]) and (!@resource.respond_to?(:active_for_authentication?) or @resource.active_for_authentication?)
    # create client id
    @client_id = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
    @token     = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)

    #  !! Next line is line 37 with the error !!
    @resource.tokens[@client_id] = {  
      token: BCrypt::Password.create(@token),
      expiry: (Time.now + DeviseTokenAuth.token_lifespan).to_i
    }
    @resource.save

    sign_in(:user, @resource, store: false, bypass: false)
```

I've added `devise_token_auth` to an existing project so it's very possible that I've created bad data in the `tokens` column. I've tried various ways of defaulting `token` json into my existing users including mimicking the code in the `sessions_controller`.

```
add_column :users, :tokens, :json, null: false, default: {}

User.reset_column_information
client_id = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
token     = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)

User.find_each do |user|
  user.uid = user.email
  user.provider = 'email'
  user.tokens[client_id] = {
      token: BCrypt::Password.create(token),
      expiry: (Time.now + DeviseTokenAuth.token_lifespan).to_i
  }
  user.save!
end
```

I've seen a mention of this in [issue #101](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/101), but that didn't have a specific resolution. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: For me, this only seems to happen when I run my rails app on Heroku. My local instance does not have this issue. I noticed my Postgres version (9.6.2) locally differed from the Heroku version (9.6.4). Not sure if that is causing the issue or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out I needed to set the `tokens` to `nil`, and then devise will take care of setting that for me. I found the answer in [this devise issue.](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/121)

```
def change
  add_column :users, :provider, :string, null: false, default: "email"
  add_column :users, :uid, :string, null: false, default: ""
  add_column :users, :tokens, :text

  reversible do |direction|
    direction.up do
      User.find_each do |user|
        user.uid = user.email
        user.tokens = nil
        user.save!
      end
    end
  end

  add_index :users, [:uid, :provider], unique: true
end
```

Comment: happened with me when i was testing new version of devise-token-auth on staging, and when old master was deployed auth stopped working with this and other errors, this fixed them all. Thanks.